# How to format correctly the output from Group-object

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'am developing a script for one of our clients, they are using some accounting apps that need to be closed on the terminal server in order to update the apps from time to time.

I've came up with a script that will ask what the user want to do and then show him the correct out put, the thing is, that my out put looks like a hashtable when, and I don't know what to do in order to group the output correctly and organize it by the process name

here is a part of the code:

`$apps = Get-Process CpaPlus,ShklMnNT,HonProj,hisMain,hazharon -IncludeUserName`

`$apps|Group-Object ProcessName`

the output looks like that:

```
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                                             
    4 CpaPlus                   {@{UserName=bla\user; ProcessName=CpaPlus}, @{UserName=bla\user; ProcessName=CpaPlus}, @{UserName=bla\user; ProcessName=CpaP...
    2 hisMain                   {@{UserName=bla\user; ProcessName=hisMain}, @{UserName=bla\user; ProcessName=hisMain}}
```

disaired output:

```
count  processname   user
----   ----------    ---
4       cpaplus      michael
```

thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: use a calculated property in a `Select-Object` pipeline step to get the part of the `Group` property that you actually want.

Comment: @lee_dailey  thank you for your help, what do you mean by "calculated property"?
i've tried to do it like that ```$apps|select username, processname |Group-Object -Property processname``` but it didn't work

Comment: @WebsGhost what should happen if multiple users own processes with the same name?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen when i use select object, it shows two columns with "username" and "processname" when under username it shows domain\username and under "processname" it shows witch user use witch process, so in that case it should show the user near the two process in the list user1 - process1 and user 1 - process2

Comment: @WebsGhost - take a look at the results of a search for `powershell select-object calculated property`. [*grin*] also, you need to run the `Group-Obect` 1st and the `Select-Object` 2nd - otherwise the needed properties are not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group on both `ProcessName` and `UserName`, you'll have to tell `Group-Object` to do both:

```bsh
$ProcessByUser = $apps |Group-Object ProcessName,UserName
```

We can then use `Select-Object` to grab the relevant properties from one of the existing objects:

```bsh
$ProcessByUser |Select-Object Count,@{Name='ProcessName';Expression={$_.Groups[0].ProcessName}},@{Name='UserName';Expression={$_.Groups[0].UserName}}
```

Comment: I've tried that, but i'm getting in the column "count" 1 and "processname" and "username"   are empty